# Classroom Seating Planning Software

Tags: open-source, planning

I've been asked recently if there exists any kind of software designed to assist or make suggestions on laying out how kids are seated in a classroom at the elementary school level.

At the beggining of the course, teachers are required to design a seating plan that layouts how kids are seated on a class (each kid uses the same seat throughout the year). Let's assume each teacher have 3 classes (A,B and C) each with 25 kids (this is the initial state). Kids must be shuffled and assigned to one of the three classes. The layout of said classes can not be the same as the initial state (for the reasons outlined below), although some of the kids can remain in their original class.

The shuffling can not be random (that would be easy) and should take into account rules like:

- Should evenly distribute boys and girls. That is, every class should have approximately the same amount of boys and girls.
- Should take into account "affinities". At the end of each course, kids are required to write down which of their classmates they like and dislike the most. This information is used by the teacher to arrange the kids for the next course. The planner should try to maximize the grouping of kids that like each others and avoid seating together kids that don't get along well.
- Should evenly distribute kids based on grades. For example, all the best students can't be assigned to the same class while all the worst are assigned to another one. The average grade of the class should be approximately the same across the three classes.

As you can see, the task is not easy and obviously it's impossible to "maximize" the three rules described above at the same time. I also admit that this is a very specific problem, but if there exists some kind of software that can assist in this process it would be a huge time saver for teachers that have to design this layouts.

The closest I found is this:

https://pages.classcharts.com/#SeatingPlans

Although it looks like it's meant to track progress of students rather than make suggestions on how to seat people.

Any suggestion is welcome. At the moment it does not really matter in which OS it runs or if it's web-based.

Comment: I doubt if you will meet those requirements off the shelf. I would recommend either 1) search https://sourceforge.net/directory/os:windows/?q=classroom 2) code it yourself 3) have someone code it on a site like fiverr - but expect to pay a few $100 4) ask the link you gave to customize something for you (for $$$) https://pages.classcharts.com/demo/